# Selecting highest value ID of two overlapping buffered points using QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, expression, select

I have a set of points in a QGIS layer.
These are trees that have been removed over time.
Often the same location has had multiple trees planted and removed.
The co-ordinates for these locations are not identical.
The point IDs are historically sequential. Newer points have a higher ID number.

I would like to select the most recent point (tree) for locations that have historically had multiple trees.
Because the point IDs are historically sequential, this should be possible by selecting the point with the highest ID number.
Because historic data for particular locations is not identical, any point with another point within 4m is considered the same location.

**I would like to select the points with the highest ID number that are within 4 meters of each other.**

This will select the most recent historic point in all locations that have had multiple trees.

An expression seems to be the best way to achieve this, but I can't quite work out how to write it.

Here is a sample set of points with a buffer radius of 2 meters.

I would like the method to result in selection of the yellow points.
[image]

Here are the results that I would like the selection expression to result in:

| Asset ID | Description | Date Removed | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1032469 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8281543 | 144.9737508 |
| 1027869 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 8-Jan-07 | -37.8280953 | 144.9732440 |
| 1064880 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 9-Dec-08 | -37.8282713 | 144.9736341 |
| 1032533 | Historic Tree - Eucalyptus unknown | 24-Apr-18 | -37.8280893 | 144.9739738 |
| 1493233 | Historic Tree - Corymbia citriodora | 4-Oct-11 | -37.8277300 | 144.9730938 |
| 1064875 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 14-Jan-09 | -37.8277993 | 144.9731772 |
| 1064859 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 11-May-10 | -37.8280104 | 144.9731381 |

From all point displayed in the image above:

| Asset ID | Description | Date Removed | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1032432 | Historic Tree - Corymbia calophylla | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8282849 | 144.9737442 |
| 1032469 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8281543 | 144.9737508 |
| 1032431 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8283661 | 144.9738058 |
| 1032467 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8279952 | 144.9736055 |
| 1032466 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8279082 | 144.9735289 |
| 1032464 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8277038 | 144.9733393 |
| 1027869 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 8-Jan-07 | -37.8280953 | 144.9732440 |
| 1455306 | Historic Tree - Corymbia citriodora | 27-Aug-10 | -37.8277621 | 144.9728873 |
| 1068988 | Historic Tree - Acer unknown | 2-Jun-14 | -37.8276635 | 144.9743402 |
| 1027800 | Historic Tree - Eucalyptus unknown | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8277959 | 144.9731492 |
| 1064897 | Historic Tree - UNKNOWN UNKNOWN | 3-Feb-09 | -37.8276364 | 144.9740522 |
| 1032228 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 8-Jan-07 | -37.8276749 | 144.9727299 |
| 1027805 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8280673 | 144.9734484 |
| 1027802 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8278582 | 144.9732374 |
| 1454807 | Historic Tree - Brachychiton discolor | 6-Sep-12 | -37.8283008 | 144.9730704 |
| 1454806 | Historic Tree - Brachychiton discolor | 7-Oct-20 | -37.8282717 | 144.9730225 |
| 1032220 | Historic Tree - UNKNOWN UNKNOWN | 1-Oct-10 | -37.8279102 | 144.9728619 |
| 1064880 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 9-Dec-08 | -37.8282713 | 144.9736341 |
| 1027807 | Historic Tree - Corymbia ficifolia | 14-May-10 | -37.8282825 | 144.9736434 |
| 1032196 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 8-Jan-07 | -37.8283673 | 144.9734149 |
| 1032533 | Historic Tree - Eucalyptus unknown | 24-Apr-18 | -37.8280893 | 144.9739738 |
| 1032195 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 8-Jan-07 | -37.8283195 | 144.9733323 |
| 1064861 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 11-May-10 | -37.8278354 | 144.9729511 |
| 1493233 | Historic Tree - Corymbia citriodora | 4-Oct-11 | -37.8277300 | 144.9730938 |
| 1032542 | Historic Tree - Liriodendron tulipifera | 21-Aug-09 | -37.8277071 | 144.9738363 |
| 1032540 | Historic Tree - Syzygium smithii | 20-Sep-10 | -37.8276720 | 144.9735663 |
| 1032209 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 8-Jan-07 | -37.8280905 | 144.9731474 |
| 1032517 | Historic Tree - Liriodendron tulipifera | 22-Jan-09 | -37.8277687 | 144.9740706 |
| 1032193 | Historic Tree - Ceratonia siliqua | 9-Feb-10 | -37.8283458 | 144.9731854 |
| 1032516 | Historic Tree - Prunus cerasifera Nigra | 6-May-07 | -37.8278131 | 144.9739597 |
| 1027799 | Historic Tree - Quercus robur | 26-May-11 | -37.8277245 | 144.9731115 |
| 1032534 | Historic Tree - Angophora costata | 21-Aug-09 | -37.8281626 | 144.9739032 |
| 1032513 | Historic Tree - Populus deltoides | 28-Jan-11 | -37.8276972 | 144.9739442 |
| 1749093 | Historic Tree - TBD Replacement | 13-Jan-20 | -37.8281008 | 144.9739068 |
| 1656556 | Historic Tree - Jacaranda mimosifolia | 20-Nov-17 | -37.8284143 | 144.9728755 |
| 1455305 | Historic Tree - Corymbia citriodora | 27-Aug-10 | -37.8278248 | 144.9728755 |
| 1064875 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 14-Jan-09 | -37.8277993 | 144.9731772 |
| 1064858 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 14-Jan-09 | -37.8281135 | 144.9732431 |
| 1064859 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 11-May-10 | -37.8280104 | 144.9731381 |
| 1782706 | Historic Tree - Quercus coccifera | 18-Jul-22 | -37.8280934 | 144.9739674 |
| 1064855 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 14-Jan-09 | -37.8283704 | 144.9734831 |
| 1032439 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8278388 | 144.9733412 |
| 1032438 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8279485 | 144.9734416 |
| 1552834 | Historic Tree - Corymbia maculata | 18-Jul-22 | -37.8281736 | 144.9737445 |
| 1032434 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8281894 | 144.9736678 |
| 1027870 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 8-Jan-07 | -37.8280202 | 144.9731659 |
| 1032522 | Historic Tree - Populus alba Pyramidalis | 15-Jun-10 | -37.8279628 | 144.9741472 |
| 1032440 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 17-Nov-06 | -37.8277658 | 144.9732555 |
| 1064879 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 14-Jan-09 | -37.8282203 | 144.9735721 |

Answer (score 5):

The first thing I would do is ensure your dataset is loaded in an appropriate projected coordinate system (i.e. eastings and northings with units in meters, not latitude and longitude with units in degrees).

If your source data is a CSV output that has both pairs of coordinates, make sure when loading the CSV to select the Easting and Northing columns as X and Y respectively and use the correct CRS (EPSG: 28355 in your case).

Otherwise, right click on your layer and export it to your desired format and change the CRS to 28355 in the dialog box.

Once you have done that it's much easier to use the `overlay_nearest()` expression to select required tree points, as the distance radius it uses is in the source data's map units (i.e. meters if the source data is in EPSG:28355).

---

To select the features you want, go to Select Features by Expression from the selection toolbar (or Ctrl+F3), and in the expression box paste the following expression:

```
with_variable('nearest',
              overlay_nearest('removed_trees_layer_name',
                              "Asset ID",
                              limit:=10,
                              max_distance:=4),
              array_length(@nearest)>1 AND 
              array_max(@nearest) = "Asset ID")
```

These are the resulting features (green dots in map) with a 4m buffer drawn around each point for illustration. Yellow buffers indicate where there's an overlap.

[image]

And this is the data table - note it's a little different from yours as the higher `Asset ID` value is actually from the other feature for 3 of the 7 pairs you identified.

|  |  | Asset ID | Description | Date Removed | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 1064858 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 14-Jan-09 | -37.8281135 | 144.9732431 |
|  |  | 1064859 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 11-May-10 | -37.8280104 | 144.9731381 |
|  |  | 1064875 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 14-Jan-09 | -37.8277993 | 144.9731772 |
|  |  | 1064880 | Historic Tree - Populus nigra Italica | 9-Dec-08 | -37.8282713 | 144.9736341 |
|  |  | 1493233 | Historic Tree - Corymbia citriodora | 4-Oct-11 | -37.82773 | 144.9730938 |
|  |  | 1552834 | Historic Tree - Corymbia maculata | 18-Jul-22 | -37.8281736 | 144.9737445 |
|  |  | 1782706 | Historic Tree - Quercus coccifera | 18-Jul-22 | -37.8280934 | 144.9739674 |